# How to get value of their object in react hooks array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

Good afternoon, I rarely write here. But now I really can't understand.

I am using React Select to display select. In the onChange attribute, I pass a function that forms the object and writes it to UseStat. But then I try to find an object using the find and
take an array of values from it.

```
const [selectedSpecificationValues, setSelectedSpecificationValues] = useState([])

const setSelectedSpecificationValuesHandler = (e, s) => {
    const maybeSelectedSpecification = selectedSpecificationValues.find(
        ss => ss._id === s._id
    )

    const objForWrite = {
        _id: s._id,
        name: s.name,
        values: e,
    }

    if (maybeSelectedSpecification) {
        const index = selectedSpecificationValues.indexOf(
            maybeSelectedSpecification
        )
        let newArr = [...selectedSpecificationValues]
        newArr[index] = objForWrite

        setSelectedSpecificationValues(newArr)
    } else {
        setSelectedSpecificationValues([
            ...selectedSpecificationValues,
            objForWrite,
        ])
    }
}

const ssTestVal = Id => {
    let result = []
    if (selectedSpecificationValues.length > 0) {
        const foundItem = selectedSpecificationValues.find(i => i._id === Id)
        console.log(Id, foundItem)
        if (foundItem) {
            result = foundItem.values
        }
    }
    return result
}

/* specifications = [
    {
        values: [
            {
                value: 0,
                label: '480 min',
            },
            {
                value: 1,
                label: '120 min',
            },
        ],
        _id: '5fe74eae07905e53ebf263ec',
        name: 'Duration',
        slug: 'duration',
        createdAt: '2020-12-26T14:54:38.362Z',
        updatedAt: '2020-12-29T08:37:18.962Z',
        __v: 1,
    },
    {
        values: [
            {
                value: 0,
                label: 'Photobook',
            },
            {
                value: 1,
                label: 'Photocard',
            },
            {
                value: 2,
                label: 'Album',
            },
            {
                value: 3,
                label: 'DVD',
            },
            {
                value: 4,
                label: 'Stickers',
            },
            {
                value: 5,
                label: 'CD',
            },
        ],
        _id: '5fe74e9107905e53ebf263eb',
        name: 'Includes',
        slug: 'includes',
        createdAt: '2020-12-26T14:54:09.267Z',
        updatedAt: '2020-12-26T16:10:16.283Z',
        __v: 9,
    },
] */

{
    specifications &&
        specifications.map((s, idx) => (
            <Select
                classNamePrefix='select2-selection'
                options={s.values}
                value={() => ssTestVal(s._id)}
                onChange={e => setSelectedSpecificationValuesHandler(e, s)}
                isMulti
            />
        ))
}
```

It is also important to understand that I loop a lot of selections in order to select different characteristics and their values.

I will be glad to help!

https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-night-kez18?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It isn't clear if you're asking about how to get the value from the select input's `onChange` handler, or if you are trying to compute the current value for the select input. I think it's the latter based on your description of "finding" some array of values. I think I see issues with both functions though.

Comment: I was able to get the value and write it down, now I need to set the value for value from the object in the array.I just need to understand how to write values ​​and output if there are many select and all this in one hook

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by "set the value for value" and "how to write values". Are you are asking how to recover the selected value from what you stored in state? It's still not clear (*to me*) what it is you are asking for or what you need help with.

Comment: @DrewReese how to recover the selected value from what you stored in state - YES

Comment: Ok, sorry for my confusion. That is what I thought you were after, and I did study your code and it seems what you have *should* work. Can you try explaining better what isn't working in that function then? Can you provide a *running* codesandbox with a minimal example of your code that we can live debug in? The issue may become more apparent when it's running.

Comment: @DrewReese I prepared a sandbox with the full code, the only one I replaced requests in the database with static data
https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-night-kez18?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like minor issue with how you were computing the value for the sub-select inputs. You were defining it as though it were a callback.

```
<Select
  classNamePrefix="select2-selection"
  options={s.values}
  value={() => ssTestVal(s._id)} // <-- not correct, not a callabck
  onChange={(e) => setSelectedSpecificationValuesHandler(e, s)}
  isMulti
/>
```

It should just be immediately invoked to compute and return an input's value.

```
<Select
  classNamePrefix="select2-selection"
  options={s.values}
  value={ssTestVal(s._id)} // <-- invoke immediately for return value
  onChange={(e) => setSelectedSpecificationValuesHandler(e, s)}
  isMulti
/>
```

[image: Edit how-to-get-value-of-their-object-in-react-hooks-array]